UV editing doesn't show
I have an object in my scene on which I can't edit my UVs. However, it works perfectly fine on the others. Does anyone know why?
Here is the object who's not working.

And here is an object who's working. What's the difference between them ?


Have you actually UV unwrapped it? (Hit U > Unwrap.) If the other object was created from (for example) a mesh cube, it will already be unwrapped.

I can't press U. When I press A then U, nothing happens. It works well on the second object but not on the first one :/

Ok sorry I did that in the uv window and not in the object window. That was that ! Thank you

Please do not write "SOLVED" in the title, accept the answer instead, that's what this function is for so people can filter the forum for unanswered questions.

Maybe no UV's have been generated yet, maybe they have been moved away, maybe they have been scaled to 0, maybe others possibilities.
While in edit mode, select all vertices and press U > Smart UV project, to have a starting point.

Oh ok it was just not generated ! I didn't know that I had to press U in the object window and not in the UV window. Thanks !!
